# Python mechanize implementation of HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: python-2.7, http-auth

I could get HTTP Basic Authentication to work using requests:

```
import requests
request = requests.post(url, auth=(user, pass), data={'a':'whatever'})
```

And also using urllib2 and urllib:

```
import urllib2, urllib
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, pass)
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
content = urllib2.urlopen(url, urllib.urlencode({'a': 'whatever'}))
```

The problem is I get an unauthorized error when I try the same thing with mechanize:

```
import mechanize, urllib
from base64 import b64encode

browser = mechanize.Browser()
b64login = b64encode('%s:%s' % (user, pass))
browser.addheaders.append(('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % b64login ))
request = mechanize.Request(url)
response = mechanize.urlopen(request, data=urllib.urlencode({'a':'whatever}))
```

error:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: UNAUTHORIZED
```

The code I tried with mechanize could be trying to authenticate in a different way than the other two code snippets. So the question is how could the same authentication process be achieved in mechanize.
I am using python 2.7.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header should have been added to the request instead of the browser. In fact the browser variable isn't even needed.

```
import mechanize, urllib
from base64 import b64encode

b64login = b64encode('%s:%s' % (user, pass))

request = mechanize.Request(url)
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % b64login )
response = mechanize.urlopen(request, data=urllib.urlencode({'a':'whatever'}))
```